# Metal or PVC Conduit in Metal Outbuilding?

Tags: subpanel, metal, conduit

I'm running wiring under ground from main panel to 100 amp panel in metal garage. When installing lighting and receptacle circuits mounted against interior walls, does  it make any difference what kind of conduit is used?

Answer (score 2):

I like EMT metal conduit.  It means you don't need to run ground wires, and it's just not a fire risk at all.  Also the metal boxes are dirt cheap!

Toolwise, you need a hacksaw and a wire stripper to deburr the inside of the conduit. A conduit bender is also handy.

Answer (score 1):

Price and ease of assembly is what I consider. Metallic or non metallic is up to you, I usually point friends that are doing there own work to nonmetalic because it requires less tools and is easier to work with and is usually cheaper.